# create file explorer functionality of the server instead of the one server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, onclick

I have a application in .Net which allows to login to different servers. How can I create file explorer functionality on browse button click of the server I logged on using my application instead of the one server I logged on with windows.

e.g. 
1. I logged on to windows with IP address 1
1. I log into my application with IP address 2.
1. I need to open the file explorer of IP address 2 instead of IP address 1.

I already have a basic functionality :

```
var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.rootfolder(v=vs.110).aspx), setting RootFolder should do this.

> **FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder Property**
>
> Gets or sets the root folder where the browsing starts from.